# Get Previous Post based on Custom Field Name, for Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I am using this query but the results returned are based chronologically (from my understanding) for `get_previous_post()`.

```
   <?php $prevPost = get_previous_post();
          if($prevPost) {
              $args = array(
                  'posts_per_page' => 1,
                  'post_type'     => 'brands',
                  'meta_key'    => 'br_type',
                  'meta_value'  => 'Fashion',
                  'order'       => 'ASC',
                  'include' => $prevPost->ID
              );
              $prevPost = get_posts($args);
              foreach ($prevPost as $post) {
                  setup_postdata($post);
      ?>

<div id="apostnav" class="kfocon"><a class="aplink" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"></div>

   <?php
                  wp_reset_postdata();
              } //end foreach
          } // end if
```

I am looking for code that will fetch the previous post based on the alphabetical order of custom field `br_name`. How could I do this please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get previous post for custom post type and custom field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324885/get-previous-post-for-custom-post-type-and-custom-field)

Comment: that was a different question, which I have now deleted since I found the answer myself

Comment: You're still trying to solve the same problem, and since the question had been up for only an hour and didn't have any answers yet, you could have just updated the question.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for which is quite more complex than I thought: https://catapultthemes.com/get-next-post-previous-post-meta-key/